# How do I use one xib with multiple view controllers?

Tags: iphone, ios, viewcontroller

In my program, I have a `UIViewController` subclass `MyViewController` and two subclasses of that view controller.

I want them all to use the same xib so I initiate them as

```
SubClass *SC = [[SubClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:SC animated:NO];
[SC release];
```

SubClass is a subclass of MyViewController, which is a subclass of `UIViewController`.  In `MyViewController.xib`, I have File's Owner set to `MyViewController`.

If I only was going to have two subclasses, I would probably just duplicate the xib but I plan to have many, many subclasses, all using the same xib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load any `XIB` with

```
- (NSArray *)loadNibNamed:(NSString *)name owner:(id)owner options:(NSDictionary *)options
```

of the `NSBundle` class. With

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"foo" owner:nil options:nil];
```

you can load all contents of a `XIB` into an array. The order of the items in the array is the same you defined in Interface Builder without File's Owner and First Responder.

Comment: Please now let me know how to use this xib with any class?